# What would cause connections to hang in the close_wait state

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

On a CentOS 7 system, C++ application is having connections hang up in the close_wait state and the daemon stops responding to network traffic. My understanding is that the Kernel handles the TCP stack management and is responsible for reaping these connections.

What could cause these connections to get hung up and what types of bugs should I be looking for in this software? For example, [might the application be failing to shut down the socket, or might something else be going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124958/tcp-close-wait-state-of-connections-unknown-cause)

Comment: Too many reasons to list. Try to narrow the problem down by examining packet traces with a tool like Wireshark.

Comment: Wireshark shows the connections closing, but is is unclear why the daemon would stop responding and if the close_wait is a symptom or part of the cause of the problem.

Comment: If all of the proper handshaking is completed, Linux should just park the port in TIME_WAIT for a few minutes to make sure no lost packets wander in late. Are you certain that the side that received the termination request sent its FIN?

Answer (score 1):

The software running on the end where you see the connections in the CLOSE_WAIT state is not closing the sockets (for example, explicitly calling close()) after receiving FINs from other side.

CLOSE_WAIT state means that the connection is in half-close state, that is, the other end closed its side of the connection but this end did not. This is completely valid in TCP since connections are full-duplex.

[image: TCP Close]

In this sequence diagram, server enters the CLOSE_WAIT state after receiving the FIN, and will remain in that state until it calls close.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't conflating the FIN_WAIT state which is part of the TCP state diagram and the CLOSE_WAIT state which is internal  to the Linux kernel?

Comment: Yes, CLOSE_WAIT is a TCP state, and indeed FIN_WAIT is not (there is FIN_WAIT1 and FIN_WAIT2). Take a look at [Section 3.2 of RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#section-3.2), pages 20-22.

Comment: @JamesShewey FIN_WAIT is terminating side of the transaction. CLOSE_WAIT is side that received the termination waiting until it's OK to agree with the termination and send its FIN. In other words, connection has received FIN, has ACKed FIN, but has not sent FIN. In the drawing above, it's the space between "read returns 0" and "close" on the passive side. The trick is finding out why that FIN cannot be sent. Is your program holding onto the socket?

Comment: FIN won't be sent until application explicitly calls close() for that socket.

Comment: And it might wait a while after the `close` call if there is data waiting to be sent.