# c++ server socket moves to CLOSE_WAIT state after client closes the connection

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I am new to c++, and i am working on socket programming. The server application is acting as an HTTP server in this case.

There is a client application requests a data, which is returned as the HTTP response. During the return of the response the client closes the connection. I see the socket move to the CLOSE_WAIT state in the server.

There is a lot of CLOSE_WAIT state in the socket connection.I have attached my code and netstat command result below, please give a better solution to overcome the CLOSE_WAIT state.

**server.cpp**

```
int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
struct sockaddr_in address,clntAdd;
int opt = 1;
int addrlen = sizeof(address);
int getopt_ret=0;
int long_index=0;
string key_u,key_v;
int iteration_count=10;
socklen_t len;
const char *hash_key_u;
const char *hash_key_v;
char type[1024] = {0};

if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
{
    logger("socket failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
bzero((char*) &address, sizeof(address));

address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.4");
address.sin_port = htons( PORT );


// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                             sizeof(address))<0)
{
    logger("bind failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
{
    logger("listen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}




 while (true)
 {
                    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
                    {
                            logger("socket not accept");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    valread = read( new_socket , type, 1024);
                    //printf("%s\n",type ); 

                    send(new_socket , hash_key_u , strlen(hash_key_u) , 0 );

                    //send(new_socket , hash_key , strlen(hash_key) , 0 ); 
                    //printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
   }
return 0;
```

**client.cpp**

```
int sock = 0, valread;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
char buffer[1024] = {0};
long arg;
fd_set myset;
struct timeval tv;
int valopt,i;
const int ASCIICON[2]={6,2};
socklen_t lon;
string ack="he";
string desc,newkey;
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    logger("Socket creation error ");
    return string("-1");
}

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, address, &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
{
    logger("Invalid address/ Address not supported ");
    return string("-1");
}



 if( (arg = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, NULL)) < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error fcntl(..., F_GETFL) (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
  exit(0);
 }
int res;
res = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
if (res < 0) {
 if (errno == EINPROGRESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "EINPROGRESS in connect() - selecting\n");
    do {
       tv.tv_sec =300;
       tv.tv_usec = 0;
       FD_ZERO(&myset);
       FD_SET(sock, &myset);
       res = select(sock+1, NULL, &myset, NULL, &tv);
       if (res < 0 && errno != EINTR) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
          exit(0);
       }
       else if (res > 0) {
          // Socket selected for write 
          lon = sizeof(int);
          if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void*)(&valopt), &lon) < 0) {
             fprintf(stderr, "Error in getsockopt() %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
             exit(0);
          }
           if (valopt) {
             fprintf(stderr, "Error in delayed connection() %d - %s\n", valopt, strerror(valopt));
             exit(0);
          }
          break;
       }
       else {
          fprintf(stderr, "Timeout in select() - Cancelling!\n");
          exit(0);
       }
    } while (1);
 }
 else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
 }


}



    char s[300];
    strcpy(s,ack.c_str());

    write(sock, type, strlen(type));
    read( sock , buffer, 1024);
```

**netstat result**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3310          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:46528       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:45112       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:47296       ESTABLISHED 11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:45766       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:45734       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:47544       ESTABLISHED 11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:46072       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:47926       ESTABLISHED 11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:47168       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:48158       ESTABLISHED 11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:47376       ESTABLISHED 11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:45274       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:46756       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:45614       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:48030       ESTABLISHED 11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:44970       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:47328       ESTABLISHED 11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:45152       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:48258       ESTABLISHED 11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:46824       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:46440       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:48010       ESTABLISHED 11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:46832       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:46856       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:44810       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:46880       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:45574       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:47128       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:44710       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:48202       ESTABLISHED 11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:45908       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send      
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.4:5000        192.168.0.3:44458       CLOSE_WAIT  11546/key_send
```

Comment: Your server does not close the client sockets, i.e. no `close(new_socket)` anywhere. There is no implicit close of the socket just because you assign a new value to `new_socket`. Possible duplicate of [What would cause connections to hang in the close\_wait state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646531/what-would-cause-connections-to-hang-in-the-close-wait-state)

Comment: Per the [socket state diagram](https://www.tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/bitmaps/state-diagram-small.gif), a socket enters `CLOSE_WAIT` when it receives a FIN (connection closing) from the remote peer and is waiting for the receiving app to close the socket.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for reply. After closing the socket in server side(192.168.0.4) its closed but in the client side (192.168.0.3) CLOSE_WAIT state still persist.
netstat result of  (192.168.0.3) -
Proto  Local Address           Foreign Address         State          
tcp    192.168.0.3:5000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp    192.168.0.3:49156       192.168.0.4:5000        CLOSE_WAIT  
tcp    192.168.0.3:48940       192.168.0.4:5000        CLOSE_WAIT

Comment: @VinothRaja per my earlier comment, `CLOSE_WAIT` happens only when a peer is waiting to close its end of the connection after the other peer has already closed its end. But `CLOSE_WAIT` is typically very short-lived since most well-behaving apps will close their socket when they detect the connection is closed. So, if you are getting stuck in `CLOSE_WAIT` states, it is because you are not closing your sockets correctly. Make the server call `shutdown()`+`close()` on the socket returned by `accept()`, and the client call `shutdown()`+`close()` when `read()` or `write()` fails with a fatal error